# Thomsen Blaschke condition

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, geometry

I am reading a paper (Paper 1: https://ideas.repec.org/p/cwl/cwldpp/76.html, that cites another paper ( [Paper 2](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/808/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01181153.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2FBF01181153&token2=exp=1441391880%7Eacl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F808%2Fart%25253A10.1007%25252FBF01181153.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Farticle%252F10.1007%252FBF01181153*%7Ehmac=d1afba28a14042f7d91eba0a55c47d6df3737b026f2f3dd1ff5a15cfb66a3085)) for its proof.
Paper 1, page 1, line 10 says : Consider the topological image G of a 2-dimensional convex set and 3 families of curves in that set such that a) exactly one curve of each family goes through a point of G and b)two curves of different families have at most one common point.

I want to know if condition (a) means that exactly one curve of each family goes through every point of G, or if there can be points in G where no curve passes.

I tried to read Paper 2 to get a better idea, but it is written in German, a language I am unable to understand. Any help will be appreciated.

From what I understand, this problem is related to given 3 families of curves in a plane when is there a transformation that carries it to 3 families of parallel straight lines. The author of paper 1 calls it as Thomsen Blaschke condition, and a google search on the condition did not help me.